# Extract an ndarray of values from a spark dataframe

Tags: arrays, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark sql dataframe from which I would like to extract an ndarray of values. Using a pandas dataframe, I'm aware that I can achieve this by running:

```
coordinates = df[['latitude','longitude']].values

array([[52.375816,  4.964433],
       [52.375816,  4.964433],
       [52.375816,  4.964433],
       ...,
       [52.362133,  4.908233],
       [52.362133,  4.908233],
       [52.362133,  4.908233]], dtype=float32)
```

How should I do this in spark?

Answer (score 0):

Converting to pandas dataframe and using the method you showed in the question should do the job:

```
df[['latitude','longitude']].toPandas().values
```

Or you can use

```
import numpy as np

np.array(df[['latitude', 'longitude']].collect())
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The dataframe is pretty large though, so I would prefer not to convert it to a pandas dataframe as it will cost me too much conversion time

Comment: I've added another solution. I think they'll take a similar time though. If you need to collect the numbers to a numpy array, you'll need to get all the numbers back into the memory.